# auto login on webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am creating a form with a Webbrowser control that automatically logs in to a site.  When I debug it, I can see that it launches to the site and fill the username and password just fine, but once it's logged in, it's going through the same code again, hence causing error as it cannot find the same elements.  Why is the program looping through this code? Did I enter the code to the wrong event handler?

```
namespace MyProject
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement username = doc.GetElementById("UserName");
        HtmlElement password = doc.GetElementById("Password");
        HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("submit");
        username.SetAttribute("value", "XXXXXXXX");
        password.SetAttribute("value", "YYYYYYYYYY");
        submit.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `causing error` and the error is....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DocumentCompleted` event fires whenever *any* document finishes loading.
After you log in, the event fires again when you load the next page.

You should check the URL and only perform the auto-login if you're at the actual login page.

(and make sure not to auto-login if a phisher sends your app a fake login page to steal the user's password)

Comment: I tried to put an if statement to check the URL, but apparently I cannot use webBrowser1.Url = "http://someurl.com". Would you mind showing me how to check the URL?  Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: I'm using a webbrowser in asp.net. Auto login works perfect when testing local but if fails on server. I Used Response.Write() and I see that username and password are set correctly and obviously login button is pressed as it repeats loading the page (if the url is the login url it navigates to default page, repeating means unsuccessful login that default page redirects to login page again). what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool is_sec_page = false;

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!is_sec_page)
            { 
                HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
                HtmlElement username = doc.GetElementById("UserName");
                HtmlElement password = doc.GetElementById("Password");
                HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("submit");
                username.SetAttribute("value", "XXXXXXXX");
                password.SetAttribute("value", "YYYYYYYYYY");
                submit.InvokeMember("click");
                is_sec_page = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //intract with sec page elements with theire ids and so on
            }
        }
    }
}
```